# Read pixel colours with OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, collision-detection, lwjgl

I am trying to do collisions by reading the pixel colour of the pixel beside object, but I am confused about how to accomplish this.

I read about `glreadpixels`, but I don't really understand the parameters, especially the last one, which is supposed to be of type `ByteBuffer`. Can anyone explain to me how can I accomplish this, or maybe a better way to do simple collision detection?

Comment: *"I am trying to do collisions by reading the pixel colour of the pixel beside object"*  That seems a very processor intensive way to do collision detection.  It would probably be quicker to retain the shape of each object and test shape containment & intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definately not the easiest or most efficient way to do collision detection however to answer your question;

```
ByteBuffer RGB = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3); //create a new byte buffer (r, g, b)

int x=1, y=1;

GL11.glReadPixels(x, y, //the x and y of the pixel you want the colour of
1, 1,                   //height, width of selection. 1 since you only want one pixel
GL11.GL_RGB,            //format method uses, get red green and blue
GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  //how the method is performed; using unsigned bytes
RGB);                   //the byte buffer to write to

float red, green, blue;

red = RGB.get(0)/255f,   //get the first byte
green = RGB.get(1)/255f, //the second
blue = RGB.get(2)/255f;  //and third
```

For the best way to do collision detection a quick search pulled up: [Basic Collision Detection in 2D – Part 1](http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/13/basic-collision-detection-in-2d-part-1/).

It looks quite useful.